# Scheme graphics

Tags: scheme

I am using mit-scheme and its graphics library. 
You make a graphics device with `(define device (make-graphics-device (car (enumerate-graphics-types))))` which opens up a window for graphics creation.`(graphics-operation device 'set-foreground-color "black")` makes the lines black. The function `(graphics-operation device 'fill-polygon #(0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1))` makes a black square, every two numbers in the argument #() is a point on the shape.
If I use the following:

```
(define (print-cell dev x y)
  (define off .01)
  (define x+ (+ x off))
  (define x- (- x off))
  (define y+ (+ y off))
  (define y- (- y off))
  (graphics-operation dev 'fill-polygon #(x+ y+ x+ y- x- y+ x- y-)))
```

I get the error `The object x+ passed to integer->flownum is not the correct type`

I don't understand this because I can use flonums as args in the #() part of the function.

I want `print-cell` to take a set of coordinates and then draw a small square centered at the points such that `(print-cell device .5 .5)` turns into `(graphics-operation device 'fill-polygon #(.51 .51 .51 .49 .49 .49 .49 .51))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#()` notation reads [vector constants](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_2.html#SEC23): you are reading literal symbols, which explains why the object passed to `integer->flownum` is `x+` and not a value bound to `x+`. You should think about `#(x+)` as being equivalent to `'(x+)`, but for vectors. 
What you want to do is possible with the `vector` function:

```
(vector x+ y+ x+ y- y+ x- y-)
```